# Java app secured by KERBEROS

Tags: java, kerberos

I would like to secure my Java web app by KERBEROS. Do anyone know what is required to do that and how much I would have to change my app if my current users are stored in MySQL database? Is necessary to use VPN? If I undersatnd right, each of clients authenticate over KDS in same domain, but my app is on remote server (not in same domain?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give us more details about the your app and your environment.  What kerberos does, it provides the way for the user to prove that he is indeed who he claims he is.  Optionally you can verify that he is coming from IP address that he is claiming to come from, although later is rarely users due to NAT / Proxies / Load balancers.

What container does your app run in?  Most of the modern servlet containers  ( JBoss / Websphere ) provide kerberos authentication out of the box.  You just need to adjust your web.xml or in case of websphere just configure the app correctly.

Do you have kerberos infrastructure in place?  If you are in enterprise windows environment with an Active Directory domain controller you already do.  In this case you need to configure workstations to be on the domain.   The simplest case is if your workstations are members of the domain and the active directory controller is also your DNS server,  and your application is running in the local domain and your browser is IE or Chrome.   Otherwise you need to do some extra configuration.

The VPN is not necessary, although if you have one it will simplify things a bit.

As for your domain question there is a lot of confusion especially with Windows admins over what domain actually is.  Domain could be DNS domain like  stackoverflow.com  and domain could be active directory domain which is something completely deifferent.  In classical Unix kerberos the kerberos domain is called REALM  and there is a configuration file that maps DNS domains to Kerberos realms.

Your app could be in any DNS domain you want,  it could be in any Active Directory domain also,  but in this case there must be a trust relationship established between different domains.

The bottom line is, as a bare minimum you have to configure two things.   The DNS server must have SRV records so that the browser could find the KDC server.   And you have to register your app in the KDC.

For more details google look [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=java%20spnego) :

Comment: My app is running on Tomcat. There is not any KDC. Each of useres is in different place (different local network) in the world. My aim is to use kerebros for secured communication. But kerberos require to authenticate users and I dont need it. My app is not secured now and my supervisor told me I have to find any way to secure it by kerberos. Only check if it is difficult or not and how much we have to modify our app. So I would't like to solve servers around, but only implementation kerberos to app.

Comment: As I said it depends on many things.   If you are using standard java security modules and roles, it is just a question of replacing the authentication module with the one that does kerberos.  Otherwise you have some coding to do. Kerberos is a bit tricky to set-up if you are not in the enterprise environment,  but it is possible.  One challenge is that users have to configure their browsers accordingly,  might not be good thing for your situation. On the other hand advantage of kerberos that it authenticates every request, so much harder to steal the session.

Comment: The Java security module. Do you mean JAAS? So is possible to define general steps to use kerberos when I haven't any kind of security? What are basic steps to use it?

Comment: JAAS alone will not do the trick.  JAAS doesn't know anything about HTTP. So you need to implement a custom filter.  In tomcat such filters are called valves.  Here is a project that attempts to do what you need http://spnego.sourceforge.net/tomcat_valve.html   I am not sure if it works or not, since I don't work with tomcat that much.  JBoss and Websphere have pretty mature kerberos modules.

Comment: Ok, So it doesn't depend on Java application setting, but on server which is app running on? On right choice or setting container. I don't need to do any more than create filter in Tomcat and connect kerberos with MySQL database with Windows Native Authentication Plugin. Right?

Comment: Pretty much,  but only if your current authentication is implemented through the container service not your custom auth code.  Also, you do need to set up KDC somewhere,  and instruct your users to configure browsers correctly.